# SQL Syntax error when using cases inside a SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

I am trying to have an if else condition in this select statement. I am either passing a `customerID` or a `accountID` into this mapper and thus I need to check which one is being passed. I had the first case where there was no `customerId` (thus `accountId` is passed), and so the inner join is performed. The second one is when there is no `accountID` (thus `customerId` was passed). Then at the end of the cases, I want to order it by descending dates.

```
    SELECT i.invoice_id, i.account_id, total_amount_due, due_date, bp.eff_date, bp.end_date, total_amount_due
        (
        CASE
            WHEN customerId = null
                THEN INNER JOIN server.bill_periods bp ON bp.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
                     WHERE account_id=#{accountId}

            ELSE INNER JOIN server.bill_periods bp ON bp.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
                 INNER JOIN server.cust_acct_rel car ON car.account_id = i.account_id
                    WHERE car.customer_id=#{customerId}
        END)         
    ORDER BY end_date DESC
```

However, when I run this, I get this error.

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN server.bill_periods bp ON bp.invoice_id = i.invoice_id WHERE ' at line 5
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  For instance there is no `FROM` clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: probably a new construct of joining tables over case statements

Answer (score 0):

use IFNULL

```
select ...,..., IFNULL(customerID,accountID) newid
from 
    table1 
     left outer join table2
order by date desc
```